# Forecast of multiple product in single instance in ARIMA

Tags: r, arima

I've a 24 months sales history at SKU level in some CSV format (the format is pasted below). I want to execute the forecast for 3 months for this multiple products in single instance through CSV upload, in ARIMA.
The code written (inspired from the Prof Dr. Hyndman post http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/batch-forecasting/.) is hereunder:

```
library(forecast)
print(system.time({ 
sales <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Red Eye\\Desktop\\ARIMA\\Sales History1.csv", header = FALSE)
sales <- ts(sales[,-1], f = 12, s = c(2016,4))
  h <- 3
fit <- apply(sales, 2, auto.arima)
  fcast <- lapply(fit, forecast, h = h)
fcast <- sapply(fcast,"[",4)
fcast <- (as.data.frame(fcast))
write.csv(t(fcast), file = "Sales Forecast.csv")  
}))
```

The issue is the forecast resulted in the Sales Forecast.csv file is of last SKU only.
The snap of the input CSV file (SKU1, SKU2 & SKU3 having 24 months sales data each) is provided below.

[image]

The output forecast  CSV file contains only SKU3 forecast value ....

[image]

Can anyone assist me how to do forecast of all SKUs in single instance through ARIMA in R. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you describe the problem, or why what you get differs from the expected output?

Comment: This case study helped me tremendously in figuring out batch forecasting: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/sweep/vignettes/SW01_Forecasting_Time_Series_Groups.html (**Note:** I am not the author!). It uses functionality from the `purrr` package and is extremely easy once you understand the basics